# Defining a location bounding box in filterStream()

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to setup a location bounding box for Austin area within `filterStream()` .

According to the documentation, it should work with a simply defined loc() input like this:

```
tweets <- filterStream( file.name="", language="es",
                      locations=c(-74,40,-73,41), timeout=600, oauth=my_oauth )
```

But when I try to bound Austin by two lat-long combinations, it doesn't works. And, in my Json output I can see: **Lat/Long not valid**

The official documentation says to start with the southwest co-ordinates, but says little about how to proceed further. Also, how to define a box using just two co-ordinates?

I looked further into location bounding box and stumbled upon a different format here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bounding_Box

According to Openstreetmap the location bounding box should be defined in the following way:

```
bbox = left,bottom,right,top
bbox = min Longitude , min Latitude , max Longitude , max Latitude
```

Also, Under Twitter's official documentation, the bounding box has been defined using only two sets of lat-long combination: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#locations

How do I define a box using just two pairs of lat-long combinations?

**Edit**

Here's the code that I'm trying to run:

```
filterStream(file.name = 'tweets13.json',
             track = c('Austin Startup'),
             locations = c(30.166868, -98.018485, 30.436016, -97.495261),
             language = 'en',
             timeout = 360,
             oauth = my_oauth)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a box defined by opposite corners? The un-specified corners would be defined by permuations of the lat's or lon's of the specified corners.

Comment: @42- Thanks for clarifying that. But I did tried using only two set of co-ordinates, one from southwest(lat,long) of Austin, and the other one from the opposite side of Austin. It didn't worked. Am I doing anything wrong here? 

Is there a reference document from where I can learn more on this subject?

Comment: You don't provide any of the code you are using, so why it "not works" is completely unclear. The example you provided (for NYC) is configured as per the help page for that function, but we are not able to critique your code since we cannot see it.

Comment: @42- Apologies, updating my answer now.

Comment: You seem to have reversed lat and lon. (There is no -98 latitude.)  Wallace Stegner's excellent book "Beyond the 100th Meridian" should have been titled "Beyond the Minus 100th Meridian."

Comment: @42- That worked well for me. Thanks! Can you add that as answer so that  I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have reversed lat and lon. (There is no -98 latitude.) Wallace Stegner's excellent book "Beyond the 100th Meridian" should have been titled "Beyond the Minus 100th Meridian." Austin appears to be just to the East of where John Wesley Powell had his fame and later efforts on land use policy.